# How do i pass a argument(array mutable) to a function from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Heres some of the code

```
PrjClass.m //this is my class with interface NSObject



//my function
-(void) printArrayToNSLog:(NSMutableArray*)arr{
     for (int x=0;x<[arr count];x++)
     NSLog(@"Index %d = %@",x,[arr objectAtIndex:x]);

}

PrjClass.h //with NSObject
//function declaration
-(void)printArrayToNSLog:(NSMutableArray*)arr;


PrjMain.h //with UIViewController
//i importer the class
#import "PrjClass.h"

@interface PrjMain : UIViewController{
 PrjClass *function;
}


PrjMain.m //UIviewController

//declaration of array(s)
NSMutableArray *myArray;
myArray =[[NSMutable arrayWithObjects:@"String",@"String2",@"String3",nil];


[function printArrayToNSLog:myArray];//[thisisthevariableclassname funtionname:argument];

@end
```

There are no errors and warnings in the code. Also tried to place break points in code it goes to the calling of the function but does NOT transfer to the `PrjClass.h` or `.m` 
using xcode 4.6.3 (not sure but Mac Mountan lion in virtualbox)

to sumerize it HOW do I call Function from a class??

**UPDATE !!
THANK YOU VERY MUCH !! ITs working now :) now my only problem is how to make the app run in background thank you!**

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not transfer to the PrjClass"?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @Rob said If you make your function static:

```
+(void) printArrayToNSLog:(NSMutableArray*)arr{
     for (int x=0;x<[arr count];x++)
     NSLog(@"Index %d = %@",x,[arr objectAtIndex:x]);
}
```

and

```
+(void) printArrayToNSLog:(NSMutableArray*)arr
```

You will be able to call it without creating an instance of that class

```
[PrjClass printArrayToNSLog:myArray];
```

Comment: so thats the meaning of the - or + sign! thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never creating an instance of `PrjClass`, thus `function` is still `nil` and trying to call an instance method on a `nil` object, which does nothing.

You want to make sure to instantiate `function` first:

```
function = [[PrjClass alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"String",@"String2",@"String3",nil];
[function printArrayToNSLog:myArray];
```

Or, alternatively, you can make this a class method (put a `+` before the declaration of the `printArrayToNSLog` method, rather than the `-`):

```
+ (void) printArrayToNSLog:(NSArray*)arr
{
    for (int x = 0; x < [arr count]; x++)
        NSLog(@"Index %d = %@",x,[arr objectAtIndex:x]);
}
```

and then you can invoke the method without an instance of `PrjClass`. So you can either eliminate `function` altogether and just call `[PrjClass printArrayToNSLog:...]`:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"String",@"String2",@"String3",nil];
[PrjClass printArrayToNSLog:myArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

you alloc init the class prjClass object like this.

PrjMain.m //UIviewController

```
//declaration of array(s)
 NSMutableArray *myArray;
 myArray =[[NSMutable arrayWithObjects:@"String",@"String2",@"String3",nil];
 function = [[function alloc]init];

[function printArrayToNSLog:myArray];//[thisisthevariableclassname funtionname:argument];

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've updated your question with an entirely different question:

> now my only problem is how to make the app run in background

It depends entirely upon what you mean:

- Do you want to run some time consuming task while your app carries on doing something else?

  In that case, you'd use operation queues (`NSOperationQueue`) or dispatch queues (a.k.a. Grand Central Dispatch, GCD). See the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) and watch some of the WWDC videos on GCD, concurrency, asynchronous programming patterns, etc. Don't post a question on this topic until you've done a little research on this topic.
- Do you simply want a little time to finish a time consuming task even though the user has left your app and gone to something else?

  In this case, refer to the *Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background* section of the [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) chapter of the *iOS App Programming Guide*. That will show you how to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to start a time consuming process that will continue even if the user leaves your app.
- Do you want to continue to have network requests running even after the app terminates?

  In this case, you'd pursue using `NSURLSession` and, specifically, background sessions.
- Do you want your app to periodically check for network updates in the background.

  In this case, iOS 7 offers a few approaches, as described in the [What's new in iOS: iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html):

  > iOS 7 supports two new background execution modes for apps:
  >
  > - Apps that regularly update their content by contacting a server can register with the system and be launched periodically to retrieve that content in the background. To register, include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist file. Then, when your app is launched, call the `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:` method to determine how often it receives update messages. Finally, you must also implement the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` method in your app delegate.
  > - Apps that use push notifications to notify the user that new content is available can fetch the content in the background. To support this mode, include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the remote-notification value in your app’s Info.plist file. You must also implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method in your app delegate.
- Do you want to just generally keep your app running in the background?

  This is not a pattern that Apple supports except in very special cases (VOIP, music players, navigation apps, etc.). This is because it's a huge performance/battery killer, so they're making sure you're only doing it for well-deserved reasons. Again, I'd refer you to [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) for more information.

Bottom line, this innocuous "how to make the app run in background" question is complex and you'd need to better clarify precisely what you're trying to do as different problems require different approaches. And before you post a question, make sure you research the topic in Apple's rich video and documentation library before posting a question on the topic, or else you'll likely receive down-votes and negative comments.